# Catch Exception , Run Alternative Code & Continue from Line Python

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I'm currently using Selenium & BeautifulSoup to extract data , sometimes the format for different pages might be slightly different, at most max 3 different type of html difference, when it came to one of the different page, i couldn't help it as it gave me an exception because the data isnt there.

**Can i do something like if Exception = AttributeError, try this code and continue from where it stopped?**

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

This is the current code

```
  price = soup.find('li', {'id' :'J_PromoPrice'})
        priced = price.find('strong', {'class' :'tb-rmb-num'}).text
        if priced == "":
           priced = price.find('strong', {'class' :'tb-rmb-num'}).text
        else:
           print ("No Normal Price Found")
```

As you can see , there is already a set of IF ELSE to detect if it's empty , if empty = find another tag for text that will handle 2 different type of html but the 3rd one which i'm facing an issue is that it doesn't even have the TAG but it does have it somewhere else.

In short, i'm trying to Grab text from somewhere else if i hit this exception then continue the script from where the exception was slapped in my face.

Update Full Trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\X\Desktop\Python\python.py", line 521, in <module>
    getLoadItem()
  File "C:\Users\X\Desktop\Python\python.py", line 57, in getLoadItem
    getLoadItemAnalyse(loop['ID'],loop['Link'])
  File "C:\Users\X\Desktop\Python\python.py", line 236, in getLoadItemAnalyse
    priced = price.find('strong', {'class' :'tb-rmb-num'}).text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Can you give us the full traceback?

Comment: Check if my solution worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `try/except` block.

So for example:

```
price = soup.find('li', {'id' :'J_PromoPrice'})
try:
    priced = price.find('strong', {'class' :'tb-rmb-num'}).text
    if priced == "":
        priced = price.find('strong', {'class' :'tb-rmb-num'}).text
    else:
        print ("No Normal Price Found")
except AttributeError:
     # Try this code instead
```

This basically means, "Okay try this code, and it *might* mess up", in that case, do whats underneath the `catch` block.

Comment: after it run the catch will it still continue to run the code below? there are alot more codes below

Comment: Yes, it absolutely will.

Comment: Yea Worked, Thanks! btw it's Try Except, catch didnt work, i did a edit, hope this is useful for someone out there :)